# jQuery droppable element id is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the li element id from a droppable function, but it just returns undefined, any idea why this might be the case?

each li element is as follows:

```
 <li class="ui-state-default" data= "<?php $row['ID']?>">
 <?php echo $row['name']?>    </li>
```

an upon dropping I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({

drop: function(event, ui) {



var ID = $(this).data("ID");
var ajaxurl = 'delete.php';

    $.post(ajaxurl,{ID:ID});
        alert("You have deleted the row successfully" + ID);


$(ui.draggable).remove();}

 });
});
```

in the alert, the ID is being printed out as simply "undefined". Any idea how this should be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var ID = $(this).data("ID");
            var ajaxurl = 'delete.php';
            $.post(ajaxurl,{ID:ID}, function(ID){
                alert("You have deleted the row successfully" + ID);
            });
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
    });
});
```

The ID param is undefined because not in the scope, and you need put the ID data param

Comment: this worked but it whenever I call to echo the ID its always 0, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the ID in the `data-ID` attribute in order to access it with `.data("ID")`.

```
<li class="ui-state-default" data-ID="<?php $row['ID']?>">
```